# How do i view my environment variables in Windows 10 VS Code or PyCharm terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal, pycharm, environment-variables

I'm on Windows 10 trying to code in Python and store variables into environment variables.

When I do 'set example=123', the command goes through with no issues that i can see, but when i go to type 'set' on its own so I can see what is stored, I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\Abrahim\Desktop\New file> set

cmdlet Set-Variable at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]:
Set-Variable : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty array.
At line:1 char:1
+ set
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I see some places suggesting that I have to set an environment up. Do I have to set it up if I just need it in that work process?
In the online course that I'm in, the person just used env directly and didn't install or set up anything. That's why I'm asking to make sure.

I tried all caps just in case 'SET', 'env', and 'ENV'.

```
PS C:\Users\Abrahim\Desktop\New file> SET

cmdlet Set-Variable at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]:
Set-Variable : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty array.
At line:1 char:1
+ SET
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand


PS C:\Users\Abrahim\Desktop\New file> env
env : The term 'env' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ env
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


PS C:\Users\Abrahim\Desktop\New file> ENV
ENV : The term 'ENV' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ENV
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ENV:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You are in a PowerShell environment. Powershell has a `set-variable` command (plus an alias named just `set`). Its syntax is slightly different from the `set` command in `cmd`. What you tried will work fine in a `cmd` window. ('compare `help set` in Powershell vs. `set /?` in `cmd`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the windows tab and type `CMD` then in the command prompt type `set` then enter.

Comment: Thanks! that actually worked! but any idea on why does it only work in cmd? why doesn't it work in the terminal of code editors?

Comment: it does work, just be aware of the path note that when you open a fresh cmd it opens on a specific path where environment variables can be accessed.